# How to Create Script for hierarchyid datatype for below data?

Tags: sql, sql-server, hierarchyid

Can you please help me regarding my `hierarchyid` datatype column as `orgpath`?

I have a table called companies, in that companyid, parentcompany_id, companyName are the fields
I need to create the "orgpath" as hierarchyid.

```sql
declare @Companies table (
    Company_ID uniqueidentifier,
    CompanyName nvarchar(50),
    ParentCompany_ID uniqueidentifier
);

insert into @Companies 
    (Company_ID,                              ParentCompany_ID,                        CompanyName                        )
values
    ('826FDFF6-E1FC-44BA-94A1-000ACEAAA8D0', '8EDB58B8-7F5C-45D1-A1BF-0004DA969109', N'BAY'                               ),            
    ('89F2A314-2C1D-44BD-84EF-00120905B95D', '671E53DE-EFBC-4D16-993B-A2BB99970A1E', N'Kuehne + Nagel AS, Stvg'           ), 
    ('088C557C-0B5F-4D9F-849E-002B3E19F8B2', '69064F08-E87C-4219-9032-25E1084B25AB', N'Quasar Energy Services'            ), 
    ('D4ADD17D-D9D8-435E-AF42-0036F67D07A7', 'E9762391-6A3A-4753-B545-0D83B6FDDC1E', N'Bryan District'                    ), 
    ('2F345CAC-2951-4B1A-9036-0037A2E3CDCE', '8C73A17C-A7F9-4E5F-B8C3-18FD8AD83216', N'BAY OFFSHORE'                      ),     
    ('5481F3FC-6384-4147-B3FB-0040BCFFB7F6', '49132BF4-2003-430E-96C8-112EE717659B', N'CETCO/NEW IBERIA'                  ),     
    ('7ABBC4C8-4196-45DC-8D05-005111BF5DDD', 'A0F84712-5D0B-48A8-9C46-D76CDC38AAAD', N'Houston Washline'                  ),     
    ('473689A9-DEB3-4D6D-B6AC-005C607317BE', 'CA7B6679-1101-4541-A3BF-A440649F17B6', N'Knight Oil Tools Middle East DMCC' ),     
    ('DC4FD87C-72CF-4782-A98A-006C5FC32997', 'A622740E-1154-478D-B917-E29F4337F3CB', N'RIG 57'                            ), 
    ('475D86FD-F8AF-452B-8E91-0070925127F1', '8C73A17C-A7F9-4E5F-B8C3-18FD8AD83216', N'BP AMOCO'                          ); 

select * from @Companies;
```

This is my data in the companies table.

```
with x 
as
(
select ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by parentcompany_id,company_id order by company_id ) as num,* from Companies
)

select * into #temp2 from x
```

---

```
; with compath
as
(
select 
    hierarchyid::GetRoot() as orgpath,
    company_id,
    companyname,
    parentcompany_id
from
    #temp2
where
    1=1 and ParentCompany_ID is null

union all

select 
    cast(p.Orgpath.ToString() + cast(c.Num as varchar(30)) + '/' as hierarchyid),
    c.company_id,c.companyname,c.parentcompany_id
from 
    #temp2 c
    join compath p
        on c.parentcompany_id=p.company_id
)

Select P.*,orgpath.ToString() from compath p;
```

Comment: Hi @KrishnaM, please can you format your code in your question. Also show us data as text not as image. After you have done that also add the result you want to get from the query and explain the query's you have added here... Do some more effort so we can invest our effort to help you... Cheers!

Comment: Hi I modified my text Please find it once.

Comment: orgpath
0x5B5B82ADE06CDFC0DA80
0x5B56B8793910
0x5B5B3B67D19C93
0x5B5B3B67CB9580
0x5B5ABE045ED8
0x5B5ABC91C37840
0x7C6B8D60
0x5B56B8F80330
0x5B5ABBEFC110
0x5B5ABE045EE8

Comment: I want Result as above orgpath

Answer (score 0):

Krishna, I think you gave us only a part of your huge table with hierarchical data.

To build a hierarchy, the values from the `ParentCompany_ID` must be present in `Company_ID`, and the root node must (in most cases) be `null`.

I have changed the data you provided, so it reflected the above rules, and below is the script I think you are looking for:

```sql
declare @Companies table (
    Company_ID uniqueidentifier,
    CompanyName nvarchar(50),
    ParentCompany_ID uniqueidentifier
);

insert into @Companies 
    (Company_ID,                              ParentCompany_ID,                        CompanyName                        )
values
    ('826FDFF6-E1FC-44BA-94A1-000ACEAAA8D0', null                                  , N'BAY'                               ),            
    ('89F2A314-2C1D-44BD-84EF-00120905B95D', '826FDFF6-E1FC-44BA-94A1-000ACEAAA8D0', N'Kuehne + Nagel AS, Stvg'           ), 
    ('088C557C-0B5F-4D9F-849E-002B3E19F8B2', '826FDFF6-E1FC-44BA-94A1-000ACEAAA8D0', N'Quasar Energy Services'            ), 
    ('D4ADD17D-D9D8-435E-AF42-0036F67D07A7', '89F2A314-2C1D-44BD-84EF-00120905B95D', N'Bryan District'                    ), 
    ('2F345CAC-2951-4B1A-9036-0037A2E3CDCE', '89F2A314-2C1D-44BD-84EF-00120905B95D', N'BAY OFFSHORE'                      ),     
    ('5481F3FC-6384-4147-B3FB-0040BCFFB7F6', '088C557C-0B5F-4D9F-849E-002B3E19F8B2', N'CETCO/NEW IBERIA'                  ),     
    ('7ABBC4C8-4196-45DC-8D05-005111BF5DDD', '088C557C-0B5F-4D9F-849E-002B3E19F8B2', N'Houston Washline'                  ),     
    ('473689A9-DEB3-4D6D-B6AC-005C607317BE', '5481F3FC-6384-4147-B3FB-0040BCFFB7F6', N'Knight Oil Tools Middle East DMCC' ),     
    ('DC4FD87C-72CF-4782-A98A-006C5FC32997', '5481F3FC-6384-4147-B3FB-0040BCFFB7F6', N'RIG 57'                            ), 
    ('475D86FD-F8AF-452B-8E91-0070925127F1', '5481F3FC-6384-4147-B3FB-0040BCFFB7F6', N'BP AMOCO'                          ); 


with Recursion as
(
    select
        Company_ID       ,
        ParentCompany_ID ,
        CompanyName      ,
        orgpath  =  cast('/' as varchar(1000))
    from
        @Companies
    where
        ParentCompany_ID is null

    union all 

    select
        c.Company_ID       ,
        c.ParentCompany_ID ,        
        c.CompanyName      ,
        orgpath =  
            cast(
                concat(
                    r.orgpath, 
                    row_number() over (partition by c.ParentCompany_ID order by c.CompanyName, c.Company_ID), 
                    '/'
                ) 
                as varchar(1000)
            )                    
    from 
        Recursion r        
        inner join @Companies c on c.ParentCompany_ID = r.Company_ID 
)
select *, Hid = hierarchyid::Parse(orgpath) from Recursion;
```

I guess, if you run the query on your full table, you will get the orgpath you expect.
(it is impossible to recover a full orgpath having only a small subset of records)

Read more about the HierarchyId in [Combination of Id-ParentId and HierarchyId Approaches to Hierarchical Data](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1192607/Combination-of-Id-ParentId-and-HierarchyId)

**UPDATE:**

The following line of the script creates the HierarchyId which orders the companies within it's parent by `CompanyName`:

```sql
row_number() over (partition by c.ParentCompany_ID order by c.CompanyName, c.Company_ID)
```

To order companies of a branch by `Company_ID`, use the following line instead:

```sql
row_number() over (partition by c.ParentCompany_ID order by c.Company_ID)
```

Comment: @Vadiim Loboda Thank you for your answer, I tried above scripts that you provided but it is not giving accurate output as I want.

Comment: @KrishnaM have you changed the @Companies temp table with your real table Companies in the script below `with Recursion as` line?

Comment: Yes I changed my real table

Comment: Does your full table have the root record where `ParentCompany_ID is null` ?

Comment: And the last control question: all the values in `ParentCompany_ID` can be found in `Company_ID` column, in other words all company records have a parent with `ParentCompany_ID` which is listed in the same table?

Comment: Yes, except 4 records remaining all parentcompany_ID can be found in company_id.

Comment: Then I'm afraid that I was trying to understand the requirements and I didn’t succeed. The code I wrote with the test data calculates the `orgpath` and converts it to `hierarchyid` format. Please provide more information about how the accurate output should look like.

Comment: Thank you very much for your. Yeah sure i will provide full information to get accurate output.

Comment: By the way, Krishna, I've notices that in your code you tried to create a number for  companies, I guess it is to order a company within it's parent childred. However in the code I wrote this order is based on CompanyName. I added the update to the post to reflect your case.

Comment: Yes, I Ordered a company within its parent-child but not getting accurate output.

Comment: Can you give your mail id I will send full data? Here data is whole data is not posted.

Comment: I believe it should not work like that, here on SO. Please try to describe your task more generally. What will someone understand when sees your full table? Are you trying to make a reverse engineering of somebody's existing work and adjust your result accordingly?

Comment: https://www.sqlshack.com/use-hierarchyid-sql-server/ I think this link can help you.